# Cycle jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm not sure if you've noticed this, but it takes the first image of the cycle plugin way longer to change than the rest of the slides.

I was thinking at first it was loading time, but it seems too significant.

I'm wondering if there is a default option that I'm missing or a workaround.

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delay:         0,     // additional
>   delay (in ms) for first transition
>   (hint: can be negative)
>
> http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html

I think you'll want to try setting it to a negative number, like -2000.